# magento custom module - 404 on index management

Tags: magento

I want to show an iframe within Magento Admin Backend, so I followed a guide on inchoo.net on how to create a module to do that.

I have now done this and the iframe is loading as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrR11.png

However, after installing this VERY simple module, clicking on **System => Index Management** gives me a 404 error like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIfsR.png

Please find the code used to make this simple module to show an iframe in admin backend in magento here: http://www.filedropper.com/companypage

Can someone help me figure out why this wierd issue is happening?

I am working on Magento Community Edition v1.6.1.0

Thanks in advance for any tips/help.

Comment: p.s. I've already checked system.log and exception.log in var/log folder - there are no error logs. i've checked nginx/php-fpm logs also.

Comment: Also, if i go into app/etc/modules/Company_Page.xml and disable the module with: <active>false</active> and flush the cache, the index management starts working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the old article on inchoo.net I followed.

This version works fine - http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Just

> logout

form your admin panel. Then

> login

again.

### EDIT:

If you still getting the 404 error,

> 1. Login into admin panel
> 2. Goto System->Permissions->Roles
> 3. Click your account(or Administrators).
> 4. No need to change anything, just save it again.
> 5. Again logout form admin panel and login again

it'll work

Cheers.